# SQL Function- IF Statement

Tags: sql, database, function, if-statement

I am trying to make a function that shows commission at 10% of the difference between sales and cost price when the sale is under 50.00 and at 20% when it is over 50.00. I am receiving a syntax error when entering the following:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION Commission_Sales 
(SALES_PRICE DECIMAL(4,2), COST_PRICE DECIMAL (4,2))
RETURNS DECIMAL (4,2)
DETERMINISTIC
IF SALES_PRICE >= 50.00 THEN    
BEGIN
DECLARE Commission DECIMAL(4,2);
  SET Commission = (SALES_PRICE - COST_PRICE) * 0.2;
  RETURN Commission;
END ;
ELSE
BEGIN
DECLARE Commission DECIMAL(4,2);
  SET Commission = (SALES_PRICE - COST_PRICE) * 0.1;
  RETURN Commission;
END ;
// DELIMITER ;
```

Can anyone help?

I have no idea what I'm doing as beginner, so it is probably a simple fix

Comment: Could you please tag your DBMS?

Comment: Only 1 `BEGIN` should exist for the entire trigger, then the handling/logic goes between `BEGIN` and the _last_ `END`.

Comment: DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION Commission_Sales
(SALES_PRICE DECIMAL(4,2), COST_PRICE DECIMAL (4,2))
RETURNS DECIMAL (4,2)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
 DECLARE Commission DECIMAL(4,2);
 IF SALES_PRICE >= 50.00 THEN
 SET Commission = (SALES_PRICE - COST_PRICE) * 0.2;
 END IF;
 SET Commission = (SALES_PRICE - COST_PRICE) * 0.1;
 RETURN Commission;
END // 
DELIMITER ;

Comment: I have added the above but it seems to be returning the 0.1 calculation in all cases- any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  DELIMITER //
  CREATE FUNCTION Commission_Sales 
    (SALES_PRICE DECIMAL(4,2), COST_PRICE DECIMAL (4,2))
  RETURNS DECIMAL (4,2)
  DETERMINISTIC
  BEGIN
    DECLARE Commission DECIMAL(4,2);
    IF SALES_PRICE >= 50.00 THEN    
      SET Commission = (SALES_PRICE - COST_PRICE) * 0.2;
    ELSE
      SET Commission = (SALES_PRICE - COST_PRICE) * 0.1;
    END IF;
    RETURN Commission;

  END //
  
  DELIMITER ;
```

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html